# How can I fix the "blank page" issue in html2pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm trying to convert the HTML document to PDF using [html2pdf.js](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js), but as a result I get a pdf with a blank first page and the last page of the document being half cropped. How such issue could be fixed ? Code:

```
document.querySelector('.save-pdf').addEventListener('click', function () {
   const elementToPrint = document.getElementById('content');

   const opt = {
      margin:       0,
      filename:     'contract.pdf',
      image:        { type: 'png' },
      html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'p' }
   };


   html2pdf(elementToPrint, opt);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved by switching the version of "html2canvas" library from "rc 5" to "alpha 12".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It really helped me. I've been in pain for three days with this issue.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Three hours of headache with searching and trying fixes and nothing helped ... and then downgrading ... everything works fine. You saved me from going nuts!

Comment: My settup: "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1"

Comment: How do you update the html2canvas version?

Answer (score 1):

you have not to download html2canvas.js 
but in file html2pdf.bundle.js and in line: 8762

change nPages to nPages-1

```js
for (var page = 0; page < nPages; page++) {
    // some code ....
}


for (var page = 0; page < nPages-1; page++) {

}
```